# after installing ssl getting wired error DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, apache, ssl-certificate

after installing paid ssl  certification the web site sometime give some visitors  [this wired error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDTbS.png)
i'm using laravel 6 the host is aws light sail Ubuntu 18

my laravel conifg in Apache2

```html
<VirtualHost *:80>
        Redirect permanent "/" https://www.sitename.com/
</virtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

DocumentRoot /var/www/html/star-flight/public

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/server.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example.key
SSLCertificateChainFile  /etc/apache2/ssl/chain.crt

<Directory /var/www/html/star-flight/public >
AllowOverride All
Allow from all
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
 Require all granted
 </Directory>      
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error message is a DNS error which indicates that the IP address for the domain cannot be found. It is not related to SSL, as browser has not connected to the site to begin SSL negotiation.

If the site opens fine for some and not others, then it could be a DNS propagation issue.

Review your DNS settings. You also can check DNS propagation at https://dnschecker.org/

Comment: so the ssl  is not the problem that good but now how to fix the DNS  i used this website and give me some wrong marks and some correct marks what that mean  ?

Comment: It means that your DNS is misconfgured and explains the problem you are seeing. Kindly up vote this answer if it was helpful, and then post this as a DNS propagation issue in Server Fault. I can review it there if you like. Just link it here.

Comment: here the link thank for helping man i hope we find fix  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60021284/a-problem-in-dns-aws-light-sail-dns-probe-finished-nxdomain

Comment: @SamEldin it's not really an appropriate question for SO. Are you able to post it in Server Fault? https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

in my case the domain name got  expired. I made the payment and now have to wait a bit